# How to dynamically change tailwindcss theme color using Remix.run

Tags: typescript, tailwind-css, remix.run

I'm using `tailwindcss` with `Remix.run` and trying to figure out how can I change some primary colors in `tailwindcss` dynamically from data I get from my server.
I've seen some examples using `Next.js` framework, but couldn't manage to do that in `Remix.run`.

Answer (score 6):

You should use CSS variables in your custom colors :

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      // Using modern `rgb`
      primary: 'rgb(var(--color-primary) / <alpha-value>)',
      secondary: 'rgb(var(--color-secondary) / <alpha-value>)',

      // Using modern `hsl`
      primary: 'hsl(var(--color-primary) / <alpha-value>)',
      secondary: 'hsl(var(--color-secondary) / <alpha-value>)',

      // Using legacy `rgba`
      primary: 'rgba(var(--color-primary), <alpha-value>)',
      secondary: 'rgba(var(--color-secondary), <alpha-value>)',
    }
  }
}
```

[TailwindCSS doc about CSS variables](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#using-css-variables).

And you'll be able to update this variables via JS.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a couple of examples. One supports multiple themes. The other is dynamic colors using CSS vars

- https://codesandbox.io/s/remix-tailwind-multi-theme-oqf7oo
- https://codesandbox.io/s/remix-tailwind-dynamic-colors-wxv097